# WSO2 EMM Publisher API?

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

Is it possible to get an application info from the WSO2 EMM Publisher (such a version, package name)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, There is a web services in WSO2 EMM app store to retrieve information about the published apps. WSO2 EMM use this service to list all the applications.

Link to the API is /store/apis/assets/{type}
and you can find the source code here[1]

[1] - https://github.com/wso2/product-emm/blob/master/modules/apps/store/apis/assets.jag